# I am trying to set the value of multiple cells when the value of once cell changes in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I am trying to set the values of several cells in the same row of a cell that I am changing.

IF the value in AJ2 is True then the range AK2:AX2 should also be true.If I change AJ2 to false, then I should be able to uncheck any of the values in the range and they would then be false.  I 'sort of' have this logic working.  IF I have AJ2 checked and uncheck AK2, when I uncheck AJ2 it rechecks AK2.

I also need this to happen on all rows if I change the value in the column of AJ for their rows. not just row 2.  I am fairly new to working with sheets and could use some help.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cell = ss.getRange("AJ2"); 
var range =ss.getRange("AK2:AX2")
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 36&&ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="MasterData") {

if (Cell = "TRUE")
 range.setValue("TRUE")}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = e.range;
  // AJ = column 36 (master column)
  if(sheet.getName() == "MasterData" && cell.getColumn()==36 && cell.isChecked()){
    sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),37,1,14).setValue('TRUE')
  }
  // individual columns : 37 (AK) to 50 (AX)
  if(sheet.getName() == "MasterData" && cell.getColumn()>=37 && cell.getColumn()<=50 && !cell.isChecked()){
    sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),36,1,1).setValue('FALSE')
  }
}
```

## explanation

when a box is checked in column 36 (AJ = 'master column'), all the boxes of the same row between 37 to 50 (AK to AX) will be checked

when an individual box is unchecked between column 37 to 50 (AK to AX) the master box of the same row will be also unchecked

## reference

[onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thx TheMaster, I will complete my answer.

Comment: Thank you this worked!!  I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The [onEdit(e) simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) returns an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

The event object contains the information about the spreadsheet that was edited, which you use instead of the "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()"

To access the information in the event object, you need to use the 'e':

```
function onEdit(e) {

  //the sheet that was edited
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  //the cell that was edited
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  //the row number of the cell that was edited
  var row = cell.getRow();

  //the column number of the cell that was edited
  var column = cell.getColumn();
```

From there, proceed as you normally would with sheets and ranges.

To update multiple cells at once, you can set the range with [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and then [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)). Note that it's setValues(), not setValue().